# Maximum update depth exceeded with useEffect & map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am facing this when I am trying to set form error object. Basically, I want to show the errors below each input field. In response, I am getting an array of objects how do I set to my error object?

Error - Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { register } from "../actions/userActions";
const Register = () => {
    const [countriesList, setCountriesList] = useState("");
    const [userRegistration, setUserRegistration] = useState({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        fullAddress: "",
        city: "",
        zipCode: "",
        country: "",
        phone: "",
        terms: true,
    });
    const [userRegistrationError, setUserRegistrationError] = useState({
        firstNameError: "",
        lastNameError: "",
        emailError: "",
        passwordError: "",
        fullAddressError: "",
        cityError: "",
        zipCodeError: "",
        countryError: "",
        phoneError: "",
        termsError: "",
    });
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const userRegister = useSelector((state) => state.userRegister);
    const { loading, errors, success } = userRegister;

    useEffect(() => {
        const countries = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get(
                    `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`
                );
                setCountriesList(data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        };
        countries();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleErrors = (errors) => {
            errors.map((error) => {
                if (error.param === "firstname") {
                    setUserRegistrationError({
                        ...userRegistrationError,
                        firstNameError: error.msg,
                    });
                }
                if (error.param === "email") {
                    setUserRegistrationError({
                        ...userRegistrationError,
                        emailError: error.msg,
                    });
                }
                return null;
            });
        };
        if (errors) {
            handleErrors(errors);
        }
    }, [errors, setUserRegistrationError]);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setUserRegistration({ ...userRegistration, [name]: value });
    };
    const handleChkChange = (e) => {
        const checked = e.target.checked;
        console.log(checked);
        setUserRegistration({ ...userRegistration, terms: checked });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            dispatch(register());
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div className="form_container">
            <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="row no-gutters">
                    <div className="col-6 pr-1">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="firstName"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="First Name*"
                                    value={userRegistration.firstName}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <p className="form-vald-error">
                                    {userRegistrationError.firstNameError &&
                                        userRegistrationError.firstNameError}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6 pr-1">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="lastName"
                                placeholder="Last Name*"
                                value={userRegistration.lastName}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <p className="form-vald-error">
                                {userRegistrationError.lastNameError &&
                                    userRegistrationError.lastNameError}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div className="private box">
                    <div className="row no-gutters">
                        <div className="col-6 pr-1">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="email"
                                    id="email_2"
                                    placeholder="Email*"
                                    value={userRegistration.email}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <p className="form-vald-error">
                                    {userRegistrationError.emailError &&
                                        userRegistrationError.emailError}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-6 pl-1">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="password"
                                    id="password_in_2"
                                    placeholder="Password*"
                                    value={userRegistration.password}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <p className="form-vald-error">
                                    {userRegistrationError.passwordError &&
                                        userRegistrationError.passwordError}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="fullAddress"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Full Address*"
                                    value={userRegistration.fullAddress}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <p className="form-vald-error">
                                    {userRegistrationError.fullAddressError &&
                                        userRegistrationError.fullAddressError}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* /row */}
                    <div className="row no-gutters">
                        <div className="col-6 pr-1">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="City*"
                                    name="city"
                                    value={userRegistration.city}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <p className="form-vald-error">
                                    {userRegistrationError.cityError &&
                                        userRegistrationError.cityError}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-6 pl-1">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Postal Code*"
                                    name="zipCode"
                                    value={userRegistration.zipCode}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <p className="form-vald-error">
                                    {userRegistrationError.zipCodeError &&
                                        userRegistrationError.zipCodeError}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* /row */}
                    <div className="row no-gutters">
                        <div className="col-6 pr-1">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="custom-select-form">
                                    <select
                                        className="wide add_bottom_10 form-control"
                                        name="country"
                                        id="country"
                                        value={userRegistration.country}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                    >
                                        <option>Country*</option>
                                        {countriesList &&
                                            countriesList.map((country) => (
                                                <option
                                                    key={country.alpha2Code}
                                                    value={country.alpha2Code}
                                                >
                                                    {country.name}
                                                </option>
                                            ))}
                                    </select>
                                    <p className="form-vald-error">
                                        {userRegistrationError.countryError &&
                                            userRegistrationError.countryError}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-6 pl-1">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Telephone *"
                                    name="phone"
                                    value={userRegistration.phone}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <p className="form-vald-error">
                                    {userRegistrationError.phoneError &&
                                        userRegistrationError.phoneError}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* /row */}
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="container_check">
                        Accept <Link to="#0">Terms and conditions</Link>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="terms"
                            checked={userRegistration.terms}
                            onChange={handleChkChange}
                        />
                        <span className="checkmark" />
                        <p className="form-vald-error">
                            {userRegistrationError.termsError &&
                                userRegistrationError.termsError}
                        </p>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="text-center">
                    <input
                        type="submit"
                        defaultValue="Register"
                        className="btn_1 full-width"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: We need to see JSX, it will help us.

Comment: No problem with jsx only the second useEffect causing this but i dnt know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your effect depends on `userRegistrationError` which is an object, reference based. Each time `useEffect` runs,`setUserRegistrationError`
creates a new object reference, which leads to an infinite loop since references won't be the same as the previous one.

One approach to avoid this issue and keep the right references, is to pass a callback function to `setUserRegistrationError` instead than a value. This way `userRegistrationError` is no longer a dependency, it will be an argument to your function instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleErrors = (errors) => {
        errors.forEach((error) => {
            if (error.param === "firstName") {
                // here you pass a callback function instead, and userRegistrationError is no longer a dependency
                // and returns the next state as expected
                setUserRegistrationError(userRegistrationError => ({
                    ...userRegistrationError,
                    firstNameError: error.msg,
                }));
            }
            if (error.param === "email") {
                setUserRegistrationError(userRegistrationError => ({
                    ...userRegistrationError,
                    emailError: error.msg,
                }));
            }
        });
    };
    if (errors) {
        handleErrors(errors);
    }
}, [errors, setUserRegistrationError]);
```

Comment: i have tried your edit but its not working now its not running infinite but setting the last error value only that is email not both first name and email

Comment: i believe the issue is firstname should be camelcase `firstName` given your input right? fwiw you should use `forEach` instead of `map` when you are just iterating over an array

Comment: no issues with param looks like in the set function i have to write like this (userRegistrationError) => ({ ...userRegistrationError, firstNameError: error.msg, })

Comment: @NeerajMishra well, but that's the exactly how I posted my answer first...

Comment: I told at answer to pass a function instead (_it's also in the code_), I believe you may have not seen that

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the second useEffect, the first time you update your state **userRegistrationError**, the component re-rendered and re-executed the **useeffect** because the dependency **userRegistrationError** has changed and the process gets repeated again because the state gets updated every render.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const handleErrors = (errors) => {
            errors.map((error) => {
                if (error.param === "firstname") {
                    setUserRegistrationError({
                        ...userRegistrationError,
                        firstNameError: error.msg,
                    });
                }
                if (error.param === "email") {
                    setUserRegistrationError({
                        ...userRegistrationError,
                        emailError: error.msg,
                    });
                }
                return null;
            });
        };
        if (errors) {
            handleErrors(errors);
        }
    }, [errors, setUserRegistrationError ]); //replace userRegistrationError by setUserRegistrationError
```

Comment: I got that part but i am new to react and dnt know how to fix it. I tried defining handleErrors outside but it doesn't work. Can you please help?

Comment: Look at my answer replace  [errors, userRegistrationError] by  [errors, setUserRegistrationError ]

Comment: i am not seeing that but its not working eslint is complaining. I am adding the whole code

Comment: Just ignore eslint and test your code with [errors, setUserRegistrationError ] .

Comment: i have tried your edit but its not working now its not running infinite but setting the last error value only that is email not both first name and email

Comment: Replace this                 if (error.param === "firstname")  to  if (error.param === "firstName")

Comment: no issues with param looks like in the set function i have to write like this (userRegistrationError) => ({
      ...userRegistrationError,
      firstNameError: error.msg,
     })